# Adjoint of the boundary trace operator?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, trace, adjoint-operators

I am having difficulties defining the adjoint of the ``restriction-to-boundary'' operator for continuous functions, to a more general Sobolev setting and the notion of the trace. I'll illustrate the idea first with continuous functions.

Assume $u\in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$ and define $\text{Tr}~u = u\big|_{\partial\Omega}$. Very formally, if I take $v\in C^0(\partial\Omega)$ and use $L^2$ inner products $\langle,\rangle$:

$
\langle \text{Tr}~u,v\rangle_{L^2(\partial\Omega)} = \int_{\partial\Omega} (\text{Tr}~u)v~dS_x \overset{(1)}{=} \int_\Omega u (\text{Tr}^\dagger~v)~dx = \langle u, \text{Tr}^\dagger~v\rangle_{L^2(\Omega)},
$

where in (1) I am defining $\text{Tr}^\dagger~v$ as

$
\text{Tr}^\dagger~v = \left\{\begin{array}{lr} v(x),& x\in\partial\Omega,\\
0, & \text{otherwise.}\end{array}\right.
$

Of course this is formal as I'm ignoring the fact that $\partial\Omega$ has measure $0$ and assigning pointwise values to a function that only exists in $L^2$, but hopefully the main idea comes across easy enough.

I'd like to know if this can be made precise somehow for mappings between Sobolev spaces? That is, given the definition of the trace operator $\text{Tr}: H^1(\Omega)\mapsto H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$, is there an operator $\text{Tr}^\dagger: H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)\mapsto H^1(\Omega)$ such that $
\text{Tr}^\dagger v = 0\text{ in $H^1(\Omega)$ and $\text{Tr}(\text{Tr}^\dagger v)= v$?}$ Such an operator would also need to satisfy $\langle \text{Tr}~u,v\rangle_{H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)} = \langle u, \text{Tr}^\dagger v\rangle_{H^1(\Omega)}.$ Any help and/or references you can provide is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more or less direct argument.

Let $\gamma : H^1 \to H^{1/2}$ on a sufficiently nice domain denote the trace operator. It is continuous/bounded. Is there an operator $\gamma^* : H^{1/2} \to H^1$ such that
$$
(\gamma u, g)_{1/2} = (u, \gamma^* g)_1
\quad
\forall (u, g) \in H^1 \times H^{1/2}
\qquad(\star)
$$
?

For any given $g \in H^{1/2}$, the mapping $v \mapsto (\gamma v, g)_{1/2}$ defines a bounded linear functional on $H^1$. Hence there exists a function $\gamma^* g \in H^1$ such that $(\star)$ holds (Riesz representation thm on $H^1$),
and $\|\gamma^* g\|_{1} \leq C \| g \|_{1/2}$.
The mapping $g \mapsto \gamma^* g$ is linear and bounded.

The requirement $(\star)$ defines $\gamma^*$ uniquely.
If $u \in H_0^1$ then the LHS of $(\star)$ vanishes. Therefore, $\gamma^* g$ is in $H^1 / H_0^1$, i.e. the $H^1$-orthogonal complement of the closed subspace $H_0^1$ in $H^1$. This, of course, does not mean that $\gamma^* g = 0$ in $H^1$. Also, I do not see how this implies that $\gamma^* g|_K = 0$ on compact subsets $K$ of the domain: we have the $H^1$ scalar product in $(\star)$, not the $L_2$ scalar product.

Comment: I agree this shows its existence, and from here it is easy enough to argue $\gamma^*g = 0$ on compact subsets of $\Omega$. But I have troubles stating something along the lines of $\gamma\gamma^* g = g$?

Comment: @Patrick: I've made an edit on the first point, but don't know about $\gamma \gamma^* g = g$. Maybe you can try to construct an example in 1d.

Comment: Yes I was overlooking the fact that there is some smoothness  on $\gamma^* g\in H^1$, so the restriction to $K$ argument I was thinking of won't work. I think $\gamma^*g\in (H^1_0)^\perp$ may be the best one can hope for. At least $\gamma^*g$ behaves like the zero function on $H^1_0$, in terms of duality. I still hope to characterize the behavior of $\gamma^*g$ near the boundary somehow. I'll leave the question open for a few more days to see if any of us have more thoughts on it.

Comment: There is no way that $\gamma^{*}g$ vanishes on compact subsets of the domain.  It's an $H^{1}$ function so it's determined by its $L^{2}$ equivalence class.  If an $L^{2}$ function vanishes on compact subsets of an open set, it must be identically zero (e.g. continuity of measure).  Also, if $\gamma^{*}$ were the zero function, this would imply the same of $\gamma$.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the $L^2(\partial \Omega)$-inner product in your application (whatever it is), write
$$ \gamma: H^1(\Omega) \to L^2(\partial \Omega). $$
This is a bounded operator by the trace theorem, if we use, e.g., the basic $H^1(\Omega)$- and $L^2(\partial \Omega)$ inner products/norms. Then there should exist unique $\gamma^*$, as stated in the other answer.

With this choice of inner products, the "equation for $\gamma^*$" is
$$
 (\gamma u, v)_{L^2(\partial \Omega)} = (u, \gamma^* v)_{H^1(\Omega)} 
$$
for all $u \in H^1(\Omega), v \in L^2(\partial \Omega)$. Denote $w := \gamma^* v$. Then the above equation in a more explicit form is: Find $w \in H^1(\Omega)$ such that
$$
 (u, v)_{L^2(\partial \Omega)} = (\nabla u, \nabla w)_{L^2(\Omega)} + (u, w)_{L^2(\Omega)},
$$
for all $u \in H^1(\Omega)$. This is the weak form of the Laplacian-like PDE with Neumann b.c:
$$ \Delta w + w = 0 \text{ in } \Omega, $$
$$ \partial_n w = v \text{ on } \partial \Omega.$$
In other words, the adjoint of the trace, $\gamma^* v$, is a solution operator to some Laplacian-like thing, where $v$ becomes the Neumann b.c. And what this means, no idea (at this moment right now).

(If some PDE is involved in your application, you might want to use the corresponding weak form bilinear form/inner product instead instead of the basic $H^1$-inner product. Or you might want to change $L^2(\partial \Omega)$ to $H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$. Then $\gamma^*$ changes into... something else.)